# Tomcat restart or redeploy breaks unicode characters from java source files

Tags: java, tomcat, unicode

I have developed a liferay 6.2 application using jsf and primefaces 4. I have unicode characters both in xhtml files and java source files. There a strange behaviour of breaking my characters after tomcat restart or redeploy of application and the problem is only with characters coming from the source files. The rest unicode characters on the page are displayed correctly. And the behaviour is not always reproducible.

I have read posts referring to setting the jvm's or tomcat default encoding and main suggested action was setting -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 but didn't have any luck.
I am using tomcat 7.0.42

Comment: the problem is actually after a redeploy

Comment: I have tested everything with no success. Something I noticed is the encoding of the file as UTF-8 without BOM. I know this is normal and I know that with a BOM it can't get compiled. But Some editors when they open it are not able to recognize the characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, try setting the text encoding in your project Properties>Resource

[image]

Comment: Yes I was missing that in the beginning of the project but I did the setting in eclipse and the problem is still here a few months later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the encoding of the class files. The solution was to set the correct encoding for javac. I finally discovered that in eclipse I had to edit the build.*user*.properties file to set javac.encoding = UTF-8